# What does the dafny error "type error mismatch (function expects H, got H)" mean?

Tags: types, dafny

I am using Dafny 17.2 in VS code

```
type H
 predicate Pfo(k:H)
lemma  fo<H> (h:H) 
  ensures forall k:H :: Pfo(k)
```

I cannot understand the error message

`type mismatch for argument (function expects H, got H)`

Any help appreciated   david

Added example:

```
type H
 predicate Pfo(y:H,x:H)
lemma  fo<H> (h:H) 
  ensures forall k :: Pfo(k,h)
```

Very similar error message

```
type mismatch for argument 1 (function expects H, got H)
```

but this time I have attempted to follow the solution given for the initial example  and delete occurrences of ":H" but could not find any solution.

Answer (score 0):

The type parameter `H` declared in the angle brackets shadows the global declaration of `H`. So when you say `forall k:H` you are saying "for all `k` that have type given the type parameter, `Pfo(k)` is true". But that doesn't make sense, because `Pfo` expects an argument whose type is the globally declared `H`.

Easy fix is to just delete the `:H` type annotation on `k`, since Dafny will then correctly infer that `k` should have the global `H` type.

The error message is admittedly confusing. You could file a github issue to see if anyone is interested in improving it. I guess one idea would be to make Dafny print the location in the source file where each `H` is declared, so that it's clear they are different.

---

In your second example, the only solution I know of would be to manually rename the type parameter `H` so that its name does not clash with the global `H`. Then you can refer to the correct one by name.

Comment: Many thanks.  I certainly could not have worked this out myself. When I changed the code to "ensures forall k:K :: Pfo(k)" dafny complained that K was "Undeclared top-level type or" so I assumed that the H in "ensures forall k:H :: Pfo(k)" would have been interpreted as the  declared top-level H.  Still now I know so many thanks.

Comment: I have added an example to illustrate that not all such  problems can be solved (i think) by allowing automatic type inference.

Comment: Thanks i will raise a git hub issue as I cannot see a way to teach this easily.

Answer (score 0):

My error was to add type parameters to the lemmas `lemma  fo<H>` should have been `lemma  fo`.

```
type H
 predicate Pfo(y:H)
lemma  fo (h:H) 
  ensures forall k:H :: Pfo(k)  
predicate Qfo(x:H,y:H)
lemma  foo (h:H) 
  ensures forall k :: Qfo(k,h)
```

In my defence the error message was not easy to understand but having a better understanding I wont make the same mistake.